# How to replace words starts with certain character and ends with certain character

Tags: c#, regex

Assume that i have the following line

```
update tblBattleInfo set BattleResultUser_1=@ResultUser_1+BattleResultUser_1,BattleResultUser_2=@ResultUser_2+BattleResultUser_2 where BattleInfoId=@BattleInfoId
```

What i want is i want to replace all words that starts with `@` character and end with the any character other than (a,z,A,Z,0-9)  for example those characters would be such as : `'+','-','=','\r','\n','(',' '`

As replacement i want '55' to be used

With this basically i will parse SQL queries to analyze at database tuning advisor

How can i achieve it ?

So the above sentence would become

```
update tblBattleInfo set BattleResultUser_1='55'+BattleResultUser_1,BattleResultUser_2='55'+BattleResultUser_2 where BattleInfoId='55'
```

c# .net 4.5 regex wpf

I want to use regex for this job as i suppose that would be best option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
s/@([A-Za-z0-9_]*)/'55'/
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regular expression ...

```
String s = "update tblBattleInfo set BattleResultUser_1=@ResultUser_1+BattleResultUser_1,BattleResultUser_2=@ResultUser_2+BattleResultUser_2 where BattleInfoId=@BattleInfoId";
String r = Regex.Replace(s, @"@\w+", "'55'");
Console.WriteLine(r);
//=> "update tblBattleInfo set BattleResultUser_1='55'+BattleResultUser_1,BattleResultUser_2='55'+BattleResultUser_2 where BattleInfoId='55'"
```